# How to write step definition of Calabash Android

Tags: android, cucumber, calabash

I am new to calabash android. I wrote testcases for 'Twitter' android app for learning purpose. But I feel starting trouble. Can any one help me? How do I write step definition? In the feature file I wrote:

```
Feature: Login feature

Scenario: As a valid user I can log into my app
   And I press "Sign In"
   Then I see 'Sign In' page
   Then I enter 'abc@domain.com' in username
   Then I enter 'abc.123' in password
   And I press 'Sign In'
   Then I should see my home page
```

How can I write step definitions for the above scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Follow these two links:

- [different steps](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md)
- [calabash](http://mobileappautomation.blogspot.in/)

Also try this: http://www.optimusqa.com/2013/04/10/set-up-android-testing-calabash/

Comment: Still i am having doubt i wanted to press 'Sign In' button in the first page of the app. In .rb file i wrote:... And /^I press "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text_to_press|
text_to_press = 'Sign In >'
end...
Is it right? help

Comment: For Eg this will be in your feature file
Feature: General functionality for InfantAudit 
Scenario: Create New Store 
Given I am on the Splash Screen 
Then I press the “Log in” button

And in your .rb file do this
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../lib') unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../lib')
require 'calabash-android/calabash_steps'
require 'utilities.rb'
 
Given /^I am on the Splash Screen$/ do
    wait_for(180) {element_exists("button id:'btnLogin'")}
 end