# Cucumber Step definition for android

Tags: ruby, cucumber, ui-automation, calabash-android

I am completely new to calabash or cucumber.
Can Anyone help me in writing calabash cucumber Step definition for entering username and password from a table?

I need to do something like this:

```
Scenario Outline: check for Login

Then I enter <username> into input field number 1
Then I enter <pass> into input field number 2
Then I press "Login"
Then I should see <msg> 
Then I wait for 2 seconds 

Examples:
| username | pass| msg|
| hekidh@gmail.com | pass1212 | Incorrect Username and/or password|
| sdgh@gmail.com | first212 | Incorrect Username and/or password|
| xyx@gmail.com | second1234 | Incorrect Username and/or password|
| abc@gmail.com | qwerty | success |
```

For doing this I need to write step definition but I don't know how to write it and where to write it?

I saw step_defination.rb file in feature folder so do I need to write the definition in that file or need to create another file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write step definition of Calabash Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997808/how-to-write-step-definition-of-calabash-android)

Answer (score 0):

First, inside features folder, create new folder `step_definitions` then inside this folder create new file `login_steps.rb` and now inside `login_steps.rb` you can create your's step definitions.
To get snippets, you can execute cucumber --dry-run and copy paste result to `login_steps.rb`.

`cucumber --dry-run` will find all steps without step definitions and will return snippets that you can use.